# how to solve when toString of null message is coming?

Tags: javascript

**when string is not matching, in console log toString of null message is coming**

```
 var mySentance = "I am Sufanta";
    var myMatch = mySentance.match(/susanta/);
    var s = myMatch.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (myMatch.toString().toLowerCase() == "susanta") {
        document.write(myMatch);
    }
    else {
        document.write("This is not matching");
    }
```

Comment: Check for `null` first?

Comment: or you can try and catch error

Comment: Why do you need that `if` condition anyway? If it matches, you'll already know when `.match()` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: how I check here? I am converting one variable data to lowercase. My requirement is to find a match word (both upper and lowercase) and display that word in document.

Comment: `if (myMatch != null) {`

Comment: If you want both upper and lower case, then add `i` to the end of the regex. `/susanta/i` The it's `if (myMatch != null)  { document.write(myMatch[0].toLowerCase()) }`

Comment: Thank you Squint :)

It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if there is no match it will be null, so you need to make sure there is a match before you try to use `toString()`. You can use an if that checks to see if there is a match or you can just set the string to be empty if there is no match.

```
var myMatch = mySentance.match(/susanta/);
var s = myMatch ? myMatch.toString().toLowerCase() : "";
```

but why are you doing the toLowerCase after you do the match? that seems strange. You can do the truthy check in the if and you will know if you have a match.

```
var mySentance = "I am Sufanta";
var myMatch = mySentance.match(/susanta/);
if (myMatch) {
    //do your processing in here if you want
    console.log(myMatch);
}
else {
    document.write("This is not matching");
}
```